# How do I remove the permission in Github?

Tags: git, github, permissions

I'm facing this issue when I try to push the code to the repository from my local machine.

```
user@user:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is your private key installed on the git server?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I find if it's installed on the git server?

Comment: can you ssh to the server?

Comment: Ask the administrator of your git server to add it, or if you have a web interface with a login then you may be able to add it yourself from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the remote url to `ssh`.
https will keeep asking you for password every time you wish to run `git pull/push/fetch`.

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save
- Change the remote url `git remote set-url origin <new_ssh_url>`

And you all set to go :-)

Comment: assuming you are using git hub. what central repository do yo use?